# what's wrong?why this tabbar show error?

Tags: ios, xcode, tabbar

this is question:
UITabBarController sometimes appeared error,click some tabbarItem will get right，or wait a few seconds to return to normal.

this is code

```
-(UITabBarController*)getTabViewController
{
    //创建TabbarController
    self.tabBarVc = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarVc.delegate = self;
    UITabBarItem *leftItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"积分兑换" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"jifenduihuan"] selectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"jifenduihuanblue"]];
UITabBarItem *centerItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"品牌商户" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"jifenshanghu"] selectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"jifenshanghublue"]];
UITabBarItem *newsItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"积分资讯" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"new"] selectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"new2"]];
UITabBarItem *rightItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"个人中心" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gerenzhongxin"] selectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gerenzhongxinblue"]];
UIOffset titleOffset=UIOffsetMake(0, -5);
    UIOffset titleOffset=UIOffsetMake(0, -5);
    [leftItem setTitlePositionAdjustment:titleOffset];
    [centerItem setTitlePositionAdjustment:titleOffset];
    [rightItem setTitlePositionAdjustment:titleOffset];
    [newsItem setTitlePositionAdjustment:titleOffset];
   //homeNav,shopNav,myInfoNav and newsNav is UINavigationController
    [HomeNav setTabBarItem:leftItem];
    [shopNav setTabBarItem:centerItem];
    [myInfoNav setTabBarItem:rightItem];
    [newsNav setTabBarItem:newsItem];

    UIView *backView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, ScreenWidth, 49)];
    backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.tabBarVc.tabBar insertSubview:backView atIndex:0];
    self.tabBarVc.tabBar.opaque = YES;
    [self.tabBarVc.tabBar setTintColor:MainColor];
    self.tabBarVc.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:HomeNav,shopNav,newsNav,myinfoNav,nil];


    return self.tabBarVc;
}
```

[this is screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6hlQ.png)

Comment: Post your code plz.

Comment: It may be the tabbaritem image size which causes the problem. Anyways Please put the code so we can have a look and provide you the solution.

Comment: @ManiaChamp posted

Comment: instead of `[self.tabBarVc.tabBar insertSubview:backView atIndex:0];` do this `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows lastObject] addSubview:backView] ;` and manage the hide the tabbar, manage tabbar action programatically..

Comment: @DanielXu Where did you set title and image for your tabBarItems?

Comment: @TonyHan between self.tabBarVc.delegate = self; and
    UIOffset titleOffset=UIOffsetMake(0, -5); posted

Comment: @DanielXu Try my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//homeNav,shopNav,myInfoNav and newsNav is UINavigationController
[HomeNav setTabBarItem:leftItem];
[shopNav setTabBarItem:centerItem];
[myInfoNav setTabBarItem:rightItem];
[newsNav setTabBarItem:newsItem];
[HomeNav.tabBarItem setTitlePositionAdjustment:titleOffset];
[centerItem.tabBarItem setTitlePositionAdjustment:titleOffset];
[rightItem.tabBarItem setTitlePositionAdjustment:titleOffset];
[newsItem.tabBarItem setTitlePositionAdjustment:titleOffset];
```